# Erro no T4 to SQL .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4

Ao tentar gerar o código sql com base no edmx está apresentando esse erro

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>
> Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGeneration.MetadataWorkspaceExtensions.GetAllAssociationSets(ItemCollection
>   itemCollection)    at
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingFED2D73CEED00C99E8A0A14FA9AE33EAFFDF3CAAFEE9E04D21CC913F1C5C88D960592C81A433C11663E61FD5459CF679CFD9B7275B72CA8BFB8D753DBB9FDDE3.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
>   in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToSQL10.tt:line 104    Miscellaneous Files C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToSQL10.tt 104

Answer (score 0):

A linha 104 do arquivo `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToSQL10.tt` contém:

```
foreach (AssociationSet associationSet in ExistingStore.GetAllAssociationSets())
```

Significa que o T4 não está encontrando suas associações por algum motivo. Duas hipóteses:

1. Suas associações não estão devidamente configuradas;
2. O banco de dados está com a *connection string* errada.